# LINQ , How to get Max ID with "where" condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have searched on stack overflow, but find example for max ID only , I want to find Max ID for some particular condition. Something like this

```
var nRow = from p in ctx.FormControls
.          where p.FormObjectsId == FormID
.          select Max(p.Id);
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that like:

```
var max = ctx.FormControls.Where(r => r.FormObjectsID == FormID)
                            .Max(r => r.Id);
```

With your query expression you can do:

```
var nRow =  (from p in ctx.FormControls
            where p.FormObjectsId == FormID
            select p.Id).Max();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you really like query expressions, you can express the "filter and projection" and then use the `Max` extension method:

```
var query = from p in ctx.FormControls
            where p.FormObjectsId == FormID
            select p.ID;
var maxID = query.Max();
```

You can do this without the intermediate variable if you want, but I find query expressions get ugly when you need to put them in brackets etc.

I would personally use the overload of [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.max.aspx) that allows you to specify the projection inline, however... and at that point, there's no benefit using the query expression form - just use the extension methods and lambda expressions all the way:

```
var maxID = ctx.FormControls
               .Where(p => p.FormObjectsId == FormID)
               .Max(p => p.ID);
```

Don't forget that all of this uses deferred execution up until the `Max` call (which uses immediate execution) - so for example, if this is executing against LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework, the whole query will be converted to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
something.Where(t => t.something> 0).Max(w => w.other);
```

or even Max of where

Answer (score 0):

Just order by ID Descending, that would by nature get you the max ID.

```
var nRow = (from p in ctx.FormControls
           where p.FormObjectsId == FormID
           select p.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.p.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Query syntax :

```
var nRow = (from p in ctx.FormControls  where p.FormObjectsId == FormID   select p.Id).Max();
```